# Implement a vibrator in a custom view

Tags: android, android-view, android-vibration

I would like to get the `Vibrator` service from within the view class. Is this possible?

I have tried adding this...

```
Vibrator vib = (Vibrator) this.getSystemService(VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
```

... but there is an error on `VIBRATOR_SERVICE` - it cannot be resolved to a variable.  Setting the context to `getApplicationContext()` doesn't help either.

Comment: Please place ALL relevant code here. This is too little.

Comment: `Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE`

Comment: @Luksprog It now recognises the `VIBRATOR_SERVICE`, but the `getSystemService()` is undefined for my view.  What do I need to change now?

Comment: @CasparKleijne What else do you need? I don't want to cut and paste irrelevant code - it makes it confusing.

Comment: It's undefined because the method belongs to the `Context` class, so you need a reference to a `Context`: `getContext().getSystemService...`.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks goes to @Luksprog who answered in the comments.

```
Vivrator vib = (Vibrator) getContext().getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator) getContext().getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
//Vibrates for 10 seconds
vibrator.vibrate(10000);
```

NOTE: Make sure you add the permission tag ( `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>`) outside the application tag. This will also work with android wear.